# Pyhthon bs4 getting stray text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
    <li><a class="atc-group atc-group-active" href="" data-url="/atc-kodlari/1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pulse fa-spinner atc-group-loading" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;"></i>

                                    <span class="lists-rundown-no">(16)</span>
                                </a>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pulse fa-spinner atc-group-loading" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;"></i>




<span class="lists-rundown-no">(16)</span>
<a class="atc-group atc-group-active" href="" data-url="/atc-kodlari/1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pulse fa-spinner atc-group-loading" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;"></i>
                                    HERE!!
                                    <span class="lists-rundown-no">(16)</span>
                                </a></li>
```

I need to take the part written HERE!! using beautiful soup on python but it is a stray text so it has no selector or something. Is it possible to get that?

What I tried.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('anywebsite')
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

for child in source.select("#atc-wrapper > ul"):
    for child2 in child.findChildren():
        print(child2)
```

Comment: post your current code

Comment: added what I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `a:last-of-type i` to select element `<i>` inside last element `<a>`. Then use `find_next()` with parameter `text=True`:

```
data = '''    <li><a class="atc-group atc-group-active" href="" data-url="/atc-kodlari/1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pulse fa-spinner atc-group-loading" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;"></i>
                                    A - Gastrointestinal kanal ve metabolizma
                                    <span class="lists-rundown-no">(16)</span>
                                </a>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pulse fa-spinner atc-group-loading" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;"></i>


                                    A - Gastrointestinal kanal ve metabolizma

<span class="lists-rundown-no">(16)</span>
<a class="atc-group atc-group-active" href="" data-url="/atc-kodlari/1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pulse fa-spinner atc-group-loading" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;"></i>
                                    HERE!!
                                    <span class="lists-rundown-no">(16)</span>
                                </a></li>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

# select last i
i = soup.select_one('a:last-of-type i')

# select next text
print(i.find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Prints:

```
HERE!!
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Answer (score 2):

Based on your html shown you can use `next_sibling` and change the css selector

```
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')  
soup.select_one('.lists-rundown-no + a > i').next_sibling.strip() #source.select_one('.lists-rundown-no + a > i').next_sibling.strip()
```